# Configure a spring web service to accept content type text/xml soap 1.2 messages

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws

Is it possible to configure a `spring-ws-core:2.x.x` web service to accept `Soap 1.2` message envelopes (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) which come in with `Content-Type=text/xml`? If so, how/where? Our code configurations are all java and annotation based.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to process `Soap 1.2` message envelopes with `Content-Type=text/xml` by creating a custom `SaajSoapMessageFactory` where in the `parseMimeHeaders()` method, I force set `MimeHeaders` `Content-Type` header value to `"application/soap+xml"` (this is what `Soap 1.2` expects `Content-Type` to be) - thereby, I am force-changing the incoming SOAP request's `Content-Type` to be `"application/soap+xml"`.

```
private MimeHeaders parseMimeHeaders(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = new MimeHeaders();
    if (inputStream instanceof TransportInputStream) {
        TransportInputStream transportInputStream = (TransportInputStream) inputStream;
        for (Iterator<String> headerNames = transportInputStream.getHeaderNames(); headerNames.hasNext();) {
            String headerName = headerNames.next();
            for (Iterator<String> headerValues = transportInputStream.getHeaders(headerName); headerValues.hasNext();) {
                String headerValue = headerValues.next();
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(headerValue, ",");
                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    if(headerName.equalsIgnoreCase(TransportConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE)) {
                        mimeHeaders.addHeader(headerName, "application/soap+xml");
                        tokenizer.nextToken();
                    } else {
                        mimeHeaders.addHeader(headerName, tokenizer.nextToken().trim());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       

    return mimeHeaders;
}
```

This however, seems to me like a complete hack so I would welcome any alternative suggestions or comments on this!